# how to register apid in urban airship for android?

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

I have completed client side code by download sample from git for push notification in android.
After execute of app i got app-key and apid from server.
But when i opening the my account in Urban Airship,i found following data that said my app has not registered any application.[image]

What to do now?Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Have your APIDReciever recieved a valid push or registration? It's been a while since I worked with UA. But I remember I missed the line in the application tag in the manifest.xml

Comment: I have given the internet permission in manifest file, what other permissions are required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Urban airship is on maintenance mode.If u try to get apid from there ,u will not get any response.
Another way of push notification in android is use C2DM .
Try google C2DM may u get result.

Answer (score 0):

According to Uarban Airship, you need to add the Reciever class

```
android:name=".SampleApplication"
```

to your

```
<application>
```

in the manifest to get your app to listen for broadcasts.

Comment: if u added this library to your project: https://github.com/urbanairship/android-push-sample You should look in the manifest.xml and add the following line to the <application android:name=".SampleApplication"> as they did.

Comment: If your app can't accept pushes from the UA, you will never see your device in the web interface. Another step in the setup is the API-key in the debug / production file.

Comment: read this if you haven't http://urbanairship.com/docs/android_client.html and please tell me if you don't understand any step.

Comment: @ Hwa Rang 
whatever u want to tell that all I have implemented.
By using the code from "github.com/urbanairship/android-push-sample" i received
apid from server.
I have also registered account in Urban airship.
I want to know whats the next step after receiving apid.
How i registered received apid to server so that server can give notification to me
by using my apid.
so,how i give response/feedback to server for register by apid  for future use.
or Is there any another way of register apid from website?
bcz whenever i open Apid link of my account of U.A i got above picture detail.

Comment: can you please tell us how to register the apid at the website/server as shown in the figure?

Comment: Does the LogCat show any notifications that your APIDReciever has registered the device with the proper Log. message from the SamepleApplication? If there is no problem, the device should pop up in the web interface window.

Comment: I get "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Transport endpoint is not connected" exception while connecting to the ip:"75.101.197.164:1227"

Comment: I don't know where you get that error. but it sounds like a connection error to the endpoint, in this case the UA server. I need more information from the stack trace before I can help you further.