# Latest Urban airship push notification not working for android

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

In my application i used Urban Airship for push Notification, But Urban Airship push notification procedure has changed a bit. So I have to modify my code according to the new API.I followed sample app for android from http://urbanairship.com/resources/ . But this code is not working for me. I tried in different way by sending the notification from  . Actually I am getting **AppId null** for the app.

Can't understand where is the problem.
Can anyone give me some idea on **implementing this New Urban Airship push notification**.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: A similar problem is here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111847/how-to-register-apid-in-urban-airship-for-android

Comment: I have seen this but didnt got any clue ....do you have any idea.

Comment: @Dinesh Sharma am using this sample app for testing but i get the error when am trying to send the message ,"Invalid token id" ,actually i have registred my email id in google and get confirmation form there and when am run the app i can see the c2dm id,also in my account i can see the apid and c2dm id,but still i can't able to send message says invalid token id

Comment: why are you using c2dm instead prefer helium and have you register for 45 days trial in urban airship ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem has been resolved.

First of all , II am using the sample app of Urban Airship at : http://com.urbanairship.filereleases.s3.amazonaws.com/ua-android-lib-latest.zip

And one more thing , for new API to work , we have to register for 45 days free trail, the link of which you can get when you first create your app at urban airship site.

Hope this may help others too.

Comment: I did, but I still see the error message in the logs telling me I'm not a premium subscriber. So the whole thing simply stops working.